# how can I use split to get image name from src in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, split

Using javascript I'm making (trying to) the fullres version of the image appear in the dialog popup when you click on the thumbnail.

I am trying to get my image name (face.jpg) out of (images/face.jpg) using the split method. Right now my javascript applies the text "lrg_" in front of "images/face.jpg" which works if my images folder was named "lrg_images" but I'd like to trim the src down to just "face.jpg" in order to access "lrg_face.jpg" inside of the images folder. I've spent 5 hours on this gallery issue and am running out of time. Any thoughts? Thanks all.

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <figure id="figure">
        <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="a tribalface">
        <img src="images/harley.jpg" alt="an image of Harley Quinn">
    </figure>
</div>

<dialog id="fullsize">
</dialog>

<script>    
const showPic = document.getElementById("fullsize");
figure.addEventListener("click", function(e){

let pic = e.target;
let imageSource = pic.href.split("")[1];
let picDescription = pic.alt;
let picName = pic.getAttribute("src");
showPic.innerHTML = "<figure><img src=lrg_"+picName+" alt></figure>";
showPic.show(); 
console.log(imageSource);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split and get the last element in the array:

```js
const showPic = document.getElementById("fullsize");
figure.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let pic = e.target;
  let imagePathArry = pic.src.split("/"); //Split at '/'
  let imageSource = imagePathArry[imagePathArry.length - 1] //get element at last index
  let picDescription = pic.alt;
  let picName = pic.getAttribute("src");
  showPic.innerHTML = "<figure><img src=lrg_" + picName + " alt></figure>";
  //showPic.show();
  console.log(imageSource);
});
```

```html
<div id="thumbs">
  <figure id="figure">
    <img src="images/face.jpg" alt="a tribalface">
    <img src="images/harley.jpg" alt="an image of Harley Quinn">
  </figure>
</div>

<dialog id="fullsize">
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the char you want to split at.

```
var parts = picName.split("/")[1];
var name = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this.

```
var path = "full/path/to/images/face.jpg";
var pathParts = path.split("/");
var file = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1];
console.log(file);
```